# Which Window Managers are Shell Scriptable?

Tags: shell-script, scripting, window-manager, desktop-environment

I'd like to start doing more powerful things on my desktop with (simple!) scripting and would like to know which environments/ window managers support this.

Example: For web development, I have to open a bunch of things and place them all before I can work. It would be nice to have a single button that does it all with a script.

```
StartDeveloping.sh

terminal -c "ssh mysite.com"
    | [put on desktop 8, monitor 3, 400px wide, 600px tall, in lower right corner]

file-manager
    --tab "/home/me/remote/example.com/website_root/css"
    --tab "/home/me/remote/example.com/website_root/js"
    --tab "/home/me/remote/example.com/website_root/templates"
    | [put on desktop 8, monitor 3, 400px wide, 600px tall, in lower left corner]

sql-tools | [put on desktop 8, monitor 1, maximized]

my-ide | [put on desktop 8, monitor 1, maximized]

# Create a new browser instance, ignoring any browser instance already open
my-browser
    --no-remote
    --pinned-tab "example.com"
    --pinned-tab "example.com/admin"
    | [put on desktop 8, monitor 2, maximized]
```

Are there any Desktop Environments/Window Managers that allow scripting? (And from the example above, a compatible file manager would need to be scriptable too, to the extent of opening tabs on launch). I am especially interested in a workflow that uses a system like compiz desktop grid and scale for window and workspace navigation, not tiling window managers, etc.

Comment: I used to use `-geometry` for much of this.

Comment: You might look at `xdotool` for a general tool. https://awesomewm.org/ is one of many window managers with an api. gnome is programmed in javascript.... Lets put it this way you are not the first person to think of wanting to do this.

Comment: I'm not sure `xdotool` is compatible with my current setup. `xdotool search --name "Pale Moon"` Produces thirty numbers on separate lines, even though only one instance/window is open. `xdotool get_num_desktops` reports `1` even though I have 12. (I think Compiz fakes desktops). So while there may be many options, 'm trying to find a combination/stack that works well.

Comment: Add a `--maxdepth 1` or maybe 2 as the manual says to your `xdotool search` command.

Comment: `--maxdepth 1` reduced the result rows to 20. Is it counting open tabs? Is there a way to get a window ID from the command that creates it? ie in a programing language you might do something like `var MyWin = new Window('mate-terminal');` and then `MyWin->GetID()`. Then there is no searching for a window, because you have a pointer to the exact window you just created.

Comment: @JeffSchaller: what is -geometry a property of? Do all windows have it (is it part of X?) or only certain programs? The word `geometry` was too generic to find any search results.

Comment: It's an X11 property, yes -- see https://www.x.org/archive/X11R6.8.1/doc/X.7.html#sect6

Comment: That's interesting... it seems to be program specific though, and the programs that allow it use `--geometry`. On my system, mate-terminal will use `--geometry`, but I think the window dimensions are in characters not pixels. The xed text editor claims to take all four parameters, but only the offset seems to work. The window always opens at the size it was last time it was closed, but in the position specified by `--geometry`. Thunar says `Unknown option --geometry`, same for `-geometry`.

Comment: Look into [bspwm](https://github.com/baskerville/bspwm) It's a tiling window manager that can be controlled entirely though the `bspc` cli tool.

Answer (score 0):

Try [x11fs](https://github.com/sdhand/x11fs).

It expose window's state, in a virtual filesystem (much like `proc` does it) allowing for more freedom and control in what you can make a window/x11 do.

This by itself doesn't suffice to be a full window manager **but** it does enable you to have a "shell scrip-table" setup...

If you want to either inspire yourself or base your setup on an existing one, try [tofu](https://github.com/periish/tofu), which is a shell script using the above (x11fs) and other utilities (sxhkd, etc) to control windows/x11.

I'd recommend using [this](https://github.com/periish/x11fs) fork of the above project, since it is much more up to date, and doesn't have compilation errors...